# Mule File Inbound Flow : Control Number of threads

Tags: mule

I want to control the number of threads in file inbound and message processor . Suppose if i have 5 files in my input directory then i should be able to process 2 files at a time . Once these files are processed (files content is processed by message processor ) , then onlly it should pick up other files . I have tried using synchronus processing strategy at flow level , but it processes only one file , i want multiple threads but each thread will process the message right from receiving file to send the response . I tried the method which david has suggested , but it is also not working . picks up only one file at a time .

```
<flow name="fileInboundTestFlow2" doc:name="fileInboundTestFlow2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <poll frequency="1000">
        <component class="FilePollerComponent" doc:name="File Poller"></component>
    </poll>
    <collection-splitter />
    <request-reply >
            <vm:outbound-endpoint path="out"/>
            <vm:inbound-endpoint path="response">
                               <collection-aggregator/>
            </vm:inbound-endpoint>                      
    </request-reply>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="E:/fileTest/processed" />
</flow>

public class FilePollerComponent implements Callable{

private String pollDir="E://fileTest" ;

private int numberOfFiles = 3;

public String getPollDir()
{
    return pollDir;
}

public void setPollDir(String pollDir)
{
    this.pollDir = pollDir;
}



public int getNumberOfFiles()
{
    return numberOfFiles;
}

public void setNumberOfFiles(int numberOfFiles)
{
    this.numberOfFiles = numberOfFiles;
}

@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception
{
    File f = new File(pollDir);
    List<File> filesToReturn = new ArrayList<File>(numberOfFiles);
    if(f.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        int i = 0;
        for(File file : files)
        {
            if(file.isFile())
                filesToReturn.add(file);
            if(i==numberOfFiles)
                break ;
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Directory");
    }
    return filesToReturn;
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file inbound endpoint is a poller so it uses one thread. If you make the flow synchronous, you're piggybacking this single thread, thus process one file at a time.

You need to create a flow processing strategy that allows 2 threads only. Use the following that allows 500 threads as an example: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Flow+Processing+Strategies#FlowProcessingStrategies-Fine-TuningaQueued-AsynchronousProcessingStrategy

**EDIT**: The above proposal doesn't satisfy this requirement:

> if i configure 3 threads , then three files will be picked from input directory and and untill these files are processed , no other file should be picked

Indeed, the above proposal would always have 3 files being processed in parallel instead of being processed in groups of 3.

So I'm proposing this alternative approach:

- Configure the flow processing strategy to synchronous
- Use a `poll` element as the source
- Place a custom component in it, which selects 3 different files from a configurable directory. No need to lock anything because the synchronous strategy of the flow prevents re-entrance. Return a `java.util.List` of `java.io.File`s.
- Add a `collection-splitter` after it.
- Add a `request-reply` with an `aggregator` in the inbound endpoint to implement a fork-join pattern (http://blogs.mulesoft.org/aggregation-with-mule-fork-and-join-pattern/). Processing of the files will happen in another flow, while the polling flow will block until all 3 files have been processed.

Comment: i have tried that but it is going in infinite loop . it keeps on acquiring the lock on the file . What i want is, single thread should receive , process and dispatch the message . So if i configure 3 threads , then three files will be picked from input directory and and untill these files are processed , no other file should be picked. please help

Comment: The infinite loop sounds like a bug. I've reviewed by answer.

Comment: if i use synchronous flow . it still picks up one file at a time , even if the file list has three .

Comment: You miss an aggregator in `vm:inbound-endpoint` to block the flow execution until the processing of the 3 files is done.

Comment: Still it picks up only one file , it is not picking up 3 files as desired .

Comment: Doesn't make sense :( Does `FilePollerComponent` create a list of 3 files?

Comment: You mean a **list** of 3 files?

Comment: Yes . So my custom poller will provide list of three files . then collection splitter . then request reply component .I can provide you full program if you require

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice. The latest config and component code would help trying to understand the issue.

Comment: i have added the flow file and the file poller component which i am using . It picks only one file at a time even if the directory has more than 3 .

Comment: Mmhhh. Try to move the `<collection-splitter />` inside the `vm:outbound-endpoint`. If this is not authorized by the schema, wrap them in a `processor-chain` as the first element of the `request-reply`: this is to ensure only one message hits it. Also add a `MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE` property, as shown in the fork-join blog post, set to `3`.