# Fork join pattern for parallel processing mule esb throwing NullPointer exception

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mule, batch-processing, fork-join

I am using fork-join pattern to achieve parallel processing in Batch.

I have take reference of the following question :
[Mule File Inbound Flow : Control Number of threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139698/mule-file-inbound-flow-control-number-of-threads)

Since I do have too many files in my input folder, but i need to achieve parallel processing. Hence, thought of using this pattern. Here is my config flow how it looks.

```
            <quartz:connector name="Quartz1" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz">
                    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
           </quartz:connector>
            <flow name="Mainflow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
          <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="EventGeneration" repeatInterval="1000" connector-ref="Quartz1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
                    <quartz:event-generator-job/>
                </quartz:inbound-endpoint>

                <mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="file:///FileLocation?connector=FileMRTransformer" count="3" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
                <expression-filter expression="#[payload.size() != 0]" doc:name="Expression"/>
        <request-reply doc:name="Request-Reply" timeout="300000">
                    <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
                        <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
                        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  doc:name="VM" connector-ref="VM" path="Batchinput" />
                    </processor-chain>
                    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  doc:name="VM" connector-ref="VM" path="Batchoutput">
                        <message-properties-transformer>
                            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="3" />
                        </message-properties-transformer>
                        <collection-aggregator />
                    </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    </request-reply>
</flow>

<batch:job name="BatchDemo" max-failed-records="-1">
        <batch:input>
            <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="Batchinput" connector-ref="VM" doc:name="VM"/>
....
required processing.....
.
.
<batch:on-complete>
 <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  doc:name="VM" connector-ref="VM" path="Batchoutput"/>
</batch:on-complete>
```

As soon as the control enter the request-reply scope the following exception is thrown:

```
ERROR 2016-06-23 10:32:56,190 [scheduler-multithreadint019.1.2_productindexing_hybris_fh_Worker-1] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: CopyOnWriteArrayList
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : [[B@26589e4d, [B@400e4e6, [B@56b3ba17]
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap:-1 (null)
2. null (java.lang.NullPointerException). Message payload is of type: CopyOnWriteArrayList (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at org.mule.routing.requestreply.AbstractAsyncRequestReplyRequester.process(AbstractAsyncRequestReplyRequester.java:85)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
```

Alternate config tried for request part in Request-Reply processor:

```
 <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"  doc:name="VM" connector-ref="VM" path="Batchinput">
                <collection-splitter />
            </vm:outbound-endpoint>
```

But it resulted the same exception.

Only when using **MuleRequester**  i am getting this exception. If i use some java snippet to return a **collection of File objects**  i am not getting this exception, and the control is entering as expected into the batch flow. But, i do have a transformer(**DataWeave**) in my input phase of batch, and my transformer is **not able to parse this file object** (say **java.io.file** or **java.io.FileInputStream**).  Hence used **MuleRequester** so that i can have streaming enabled.

I am not sure what went wrong when using this Mulerequester??

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative for it, if anyone is interested.

Used a poll component, with Java to return fileNames collection (rather than file Objects).  Used the same requestreply pattern. However, this time i am retrieving payload from file in the **input** phase of batch, using **MuleRequester**. giving the filename to this **MuleRequester** as input path.

This way it is running fine.